# NVelocity - print a record based on a condition

Tags: break, nvelocity

i'm trying to print a record in NVelocity based on certain condition:

Below is the snippet... basically, Loop through the Addresses Object and if the current AdType is the "Current Address", print it and then exit out of the loop ...

I'm getting "#break"  in my output html... as if it is ignoring it..

I have version 1.1.1 of NVelocity

Thanks

```
     #foreach($spAddress in $Report.Spouse.Addresses)
         #if( $spAddress.AdType == "Current Address")
    <tr>
        <td width="23%">
            <font size="2"><strong>$spAddress.AdType :</strong></font>
        </td>
        <td width="75%">
            <font size="2">$spAddress.CivicNumber, $spAddress.StreetName,$spAddress.City, $spAddress.Province, $spAddress.PostalCode</font>
        </td>
    </tr>
        #break
        #end
    #end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented `#break` about a year ago, but it's not in any released version yet. You can  get it from the [Monorail2 repository](https://github.com/castleproject/MonoRail/tree/master/MR2/NVelocity/src). Give it a try and let us know if you find any bugs.